# Browserify: replace local file with NPM module using 'browser' field in 'package.json'

Tags: node.js, browserify, package.json

I am trying to browserify complex lib with lot of dependencies.
One of the libs require to switch local file with NPM module.
I added "browser" field into 'package.json' of that lib, with following content:

```
{
  "./lib/local_file.js": "npm_module_name"
}
```

And then ran browserify on my code which require this lib.
As result, I see following error:

```
Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, lstat '/home/user/dev/my-project-dir/npm_module_name'
    at Error (native)
```

As temporary solution I created 'local_file_browser.js' file:

```
module.exports = require('npm_module_name').exports
```

And change 'browser' field to:

```
{
  "./lib/local_file.js": "./lib/local_file_browser.js"
}
```

And everything is working, but I prefer not to create wrapper files if I can avoid it. Is it possible?

P.S. If it helps, I pushed my code to Github https://github.com/APIs-guru/jsonpath/blob/master/package.json#L16-L18
 And project that I trying to browserify is this https://github.com/lucybot/api-spec-converter
It depends on some libs which in turn depend on 'jsonpath' lib.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It was a bug in browserify and it already fixed:
https://github.com/substack/node-browserify/issues/1435